# What happens if to postulate that complex numbers whose argument differs by $2 \pi$ are not equal?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What happens if to postulate that complex numbers whose argument differs by $2\pi$ are not equal? What properties such system will have? Will all analytic functions be entire?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: This follows from the definition of 'argument,' so you'd have to do away with some other aspect of the definition of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If you postulate that, what will happen is equal numbers will not equal each other: $z\neq z$. Such a system has an annoying property called inconsistency.

Comment: If you want to, you can create a spiral surface in three dimensions, reflecting the multiple values of the complex logarithm.

Comment: I guess what you're thinking of is working in polar coordinates but with $(r_1,\theta_1)=(r_2,\theta_2)$ iff $r_1=r_2$ and $\theta_1=\theta_2$ instead of $\theta_1=\theta_2\pm2n\pi$. In this system, multiplication, square roots, etc. are nice, sure, but it's not clear how you would define addition.

Answer (score 4):

Your question leads to the fascinating subject of [Riemann surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface). Riemann was motivated by the fact that some functions, such as the square root function, are not well-defined over $\mathbb C$, because each non-zero complex number has two square roots. So he introduced the notion of a Riemann surface, which in the case of the square root function is a double copy of $\mathbb C$ (except for $0$, which occurs once only).

The surface for the square root function can be visualised as a spiral staircase that joins up with itself after two revolutions. On this surface, a square root function can be defined which is single-valued and differentiable. And you have to go around the origin twice to get back to where you started, so numbers whose arguments differ by $4\pi$ (but not $2\pi$!) are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Then you would have the number describing the half circle or the right angle a different name. In standard terms, the right angle is at $\frac\pi2$ and the inner angle of the equilateral triangle is $\frac\pi3$.

The definition of $\pi$ is via the right angle, in that it is the smallest positive solution to $\cos x=0$, or $e^{ix}=i$. And since the fourth power of that equality is $e^{i4x}=e^{i2\pi}=1$, you get the periodicity that you put into question.